# Carrier sensing and backoff function in mac802.11

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, openwrt

I have a Wi-Fi access point device with Linux-based firmware ( Netgear WAX220 running OpenWrt 23.05.0 with MT7615 Driver).

For research purposes, I am trying to change the backoff function in my router from binary backoff to exponential increase, and exponential decrease (EIED) backoff. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the backoff function inside the driver or firmware. I can change the minimum contention windows, but I cannot find the backoff function, which probably should be a one-time shifting of the minimum contention windows size in the driver or mac80211 sub-system files.

Where is the Wi-Fi backoff function implemented? Am I searching in the wrong files?